# Create histograms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, histogram

I need some help to produce histograms regarding my data about an **algae density collected in 8 sampling sites, 4 times a year, for 5 years**.

I would like to analyse them, underlining the differences in density, for each site, both among times and years but I don't know how to do this.

I can create a layer for each considered year but I'm not able to see how to compare with histograms the **density among years for each site**.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the QGIS plugin to analyse your data using R packages. The link above can give some tips:

http://arc-team-open-research.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/manager-usefull-plugin-for-qgis.html

Or you can export your data to one statistical software and run the analyses there. I'm still recommending R.

http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html